# Pan to coordinate on map when button clicked (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, onitemclicklistener

I am populating a ListView of map coordinates from a SQLite database of map-points in a SlidingDrawer at the footer of a MapView.

I would like to pan to the appropriate map point when an item in the the ListView is clicked.

To simply this, how do you pan to a hard-coded geopoint on the map when a button is clicked?

Links to tutorials are always helpful :-)

Comment: Hope you are aware, how to get the map coordinates from the listview. Once you get the coordinaates, pass it to the google maps as shown in this example

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/?s=GPS

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the new Google Maps API v2, you would create a LatLng using something like

```
LatLng point = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

and then move the camera to that point using [moveCamera](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#moveCamera%28com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate%29).

So, with your new point, you would write

```
getMap().moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
```

This is discussed in the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#moving_the_camera).

Comment: V2 is brand new. It came out last month. See if you can use getMap(). If you can, you're in v2.

Comment: Thanks, i built the project using Google maps api. I will have to use this new API to get this functionality.

Comment: use this instead to make the camera pan over to the coordinate instead of jump. Looks way better.  getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));